# Create a first order, constant coefficient, linear differential equation with a time dependent, non-homogenous term.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I will eventually need to solve this equation using integrating factors but there are a lot of necessary parts to this equation. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
ay' + by = f(t)
$$
Now you can choose a $f(t)$ such that you can compute the integral 
$$
\int \mathrm{e}^{\frac{b}{a}t}\frac{f(t)}{a} dt
$$